# Android Comparator not working in lollipop & below versions

Tags: android, listview

Am using following Camparator to sort the items in adapter binded to given listview;

```
   public static Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> StringAscComparator = new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        //int index;
        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> app1, HashMap<String, String> app2) {

            Float stringName1 = Float.parseFloat(app1.get(KEY_RATE).trim());
            Float stringName2 = Float.parseFloat(app2.get(KEY_RATE).trim());
            //index++;
            Log.d("comapare_tag","str1: "+stringName1+" str2: "+stringName2);
            if ( stringName1 > stringName2 ) {
                return 1;
            } else if ( stringName1 < stringName2 ) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
            //return Float.compare(stringName1,stringName2);
        }
    };
```

This how i invoked it:

```
Collections.sort(hotelList,StringAscComparator);
```

but the above code properly sorts(in descending order,highest first!) all the items in livestview in version 6.0, but below that, I have tested it on lollipop,kitkat & on jellybean; it's not working, what am doing wrong in above code, or is there any other conventional way of doing this, please help.

Thanx!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it?

Comment: yes, i debugged it, everything seems to be normal!

Comment: So you're getting all the return values you expect, but it's sorted backwards?  Or doesn't get sorted at all?

Comment: no, it's not get sorted in  20 & below.

Comment: No idea what's going wrong.  I would write a unit test to test the sorting in isolation from the UI.  Perhaps the comparator is fine but something else is going wrong with the ListView.

Comment: OK, I will unit test it!